# Trouble with HttpClient.GetAsync in IBackgroundTask

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, uwp

While stepping through the debugger, the `IBackgroundTask.Run()` method executes, but `HttpClient().GetAsync()` never returns or throws an exception. *(Obviously) nothing is wrong with this bit if I run it in a foreground method.*

```
public sealed class BackgroundHttpClientTest : IBackgroundTask
{
    public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        var response = await new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient().GetAsync(new Uri("https://www.someUrl.com"));
    }
}
```

Not sure what I'm missing here. I double checked all of the 
declarations in the appmanifest and just don't know where else to look. Is there some limitation with `IBackgroundTask` that I'm unaware of?

Edit: forgot to mention this is for a Win10 Universal app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use task deferrals when using async methods in your background task, otherwise the Task can terminate unexpectedly when the execution flow reaches the end of the `Run` method.

```
public sealed class BackgroundHttpClientTest : IBackgroundTask
{
    BackgroundTaskDeferral _deferral;
    public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        _deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral(); 
        var response = await new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient().GetAsync(new Uri("https://www.someUrl.com"));
        _deferral.Complete();
    }
}
```

Read more in the official documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-a-background-task)

Comment: You need to put `_deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();` inside *Run* method, otherwise *taskInstance* is not defined.

Comment: This is what happens when you don't reply from your dev machine where you can write the code properly. Declare the _deferral outside of run, initialize inside the run.

Comment: Would u mind to help me, man https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54759390/exception-thrown-system-typeloadexception-in-unknown-module-in-uwp-background